# Combining graphics twice

Tags: graphics

I have a for loop that produces a few line plots. After it is produced, it is appended together, and I'm using the "Show" command to combine the plots together. As shown in the example code below:

```
For[l = 1, l <= 21, l++,
  a = ListLinePlot[(mylist[[l]] + l*5)];  
  AppendTo[z, a]];
Show[z, PlotRange -> All] // Print)]
```

"mylist" is time series data. Looping through it and adding multiples of 5 with the code above allows me to produce a plot as the image below:

[image]

I'd like to now combine a few plots that are produced this way in a grid. 
I have tried using an outer "for" loop, and the command GraphicsGrid, but that doesn't seem to work. Are there any other ways I can go about this? Thanks.

Comment: what does `mylist` look like?

Comment: Hi @kglr, I've edited the question above to answer your question of what "mylist" looks like. Thank you.

Comment: thank you very much Jin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
mylist1 = TimeSeries[#, {5}] & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {21, 50}];
mylist2 = TimeSeries[#, {20}] & /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 40}];
```

(1) You can use `Table` instead of a `For` loop to construct transformed series, and (2) you can use a single `ListLinePlot` for `mylist1` instead of combining 21 separate plots with `Show`:

```
z1a = ListLinePlot[Table[mylist1[[l]] + l*5, {l, 1, 21}] ];
z2a = ListLinePlot[Table[mylist2[[l]] + l*50, {l, 1, 10}] ];
GraphicsGrid[{{z1a}, {z2a}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `MapIndexed`:

```
z1b = ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[# + #2[[1]] 5 &, mylist1] ];
z2b = ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[# + #2[[1]] 50 &, mylist2] ];
GraphicsGrid[{{z1b}, {z2b}}]
```

> same picture